# Where is the directory of public voice actions apps?

Tags: actions-on-google

Is there any way I can discover the actions publicly available ?

I have tried several Ok Google, Talk to  but I have never found any specific app. I always see the standard command like weather etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see all the action in the app itself. Click on the top-right button and you will get the 'explore' page that contain all the actions.

See in the image below:

[image]